# Port forward from eth0 (IP camera is connected to eth0) to wlan0 in same board

Tags: port-forwarding, iptables, switch

I have a Cisco SG500 switch where I have connected my IP camera to eth0. I need to port forward  from eth0 to wlan0 on this same board such that if I login to my board via wlan0, I should be able to open my IP camera on Firefox.

IP camera IP address is 192.168.17.10:7000

eth0 IP address is 192.168.17.1

wlan0 IP address is 192.168.42.5

I have tried port forwarding like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp --dport 1000 -j DNAT --to 192.168.17.10:7000
```

But this rule is not working, I can not open the IP camera in Firefox from IP address 192.168.42.5:1000.

Comment: What kind of a board are we talking about?

Comment: it is a SG500 board   which supports ethernet , wifi and usb

Comment: Do you have "_masquerade_" configured for `wlan0`? Could you share the output of `iptables -vL` and `iptables -vL -t nat`?

Comment: What is the IP address of the computer running Firefox?

Comment: i have login to the computer via wlan0 ip address i.e. 192.168.42.5

Comment: Is your wlan is connected with an ethernet-cable to the managed switch, do you have also internet access ?

Comment: wlan is connected to the pc via wireless and their is no internet access